# Can't type on TextInput when using navigate for screen

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-navigation

I am using firebase for authentication and for database, then I am trying to add navigation screen on my code but now, I can't type on the textInput. Does anyone have an idea? here's my code:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Text, Button, Alert, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { db, firestore, auth } from './firebaseConfig';
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } from 'firebase/auth';
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import {ref, set, get, onValue, Database} from 'firebase/database';
import {doc, setDoc, getDoc, onSnapshot} from 'firebase/firestore';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';



export default function App() {

    const [loginEmail, setLoginEmail] = useState('');
    const [loginPassword, setLoginPassword] = useState('');
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
 
   loginWithFirebase = (navigation) => {
    console.log(loginEmail);
    console.log(loginPassword);
    if(loginEmail.length < 4){
      Alert.alert("Please enter a valid email address");
      return;
    }
    if(loginPassword.length <4){
      Alert.alert("Please enter a valid password");
      return;
    }
}
  
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

HomeScreen = ({navigation}) =>{
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
          <Text>Sign in with Firebase</Text>
          <TextInput
            onChangeText={value=>setLoginEmail(value)}
            autoCapitalize='none'
            autoCorrect = {false}
            keyboardType='email-address'
            placeholder='Email'
            style={styles.textInput}
          />
          <TextInput
            onChangeText={value => setLoginPassword(value)}
            autoCapitalize='none'
            autoCorrect = {false}
            keyboardType='visible-password'
            placeholder='Password'
            secureTextEntry = {true}
            style={styles.textInput}
          />
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Button  style={styles.button} title="Login" onPress={loginWithFirebase} />
          </View>

          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Button  style={styles.button} title="Register" onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('Register')} />
          </View>
        </View>
    </View>
  );
  
  RegisterScreen = ({navigation}) =>{
  ...
  }
  
  return (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);
}
```

I tried to do   `onChange={e => setLoginEmail(e.target.value)}` but when I clicked the button, the `loginEmail` value will become undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In react when you are handling input change through state value you also need to set the value prop to the input
For example if you are using onChange={e => setLoginEmail(e.target.value)} then also you need to set the value prop to input i.e value={your_state_value}
Which is loginEmail in your case